# Where to keep state in a React + React-Router app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Router but I'm not sure how to maintain state outside of a component while still have components update if that state changes. I'm passing properties to components in the routes:

```
class Index extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {foo: this.props.route.foo}
  }
}

var bar = 'bla'

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" foo=bar component={Index}/>
);
```

My routes are defined outside of a component so updating `bar` in the example above doesn't update my component (nor does it redraw). What is the accepted way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). This method will invoked when you pass a new `props` to that component. Using this, set the new `state` when you receive a new props.

The following should work.

```
class Index extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {foo: this.props.route.foo}
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      foo: nextProps.route.foo,
    })
  }
}

var bar = 'bla'

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" foo={bar} component={Index}/>
);
```

Comment: Thx, but I can't get this to work, `componentWillReceiveProps' is somehow never invoked. From the code snippet I can't conclude that the component will update  when `bar` is invoked.